# How to get the value of the product after multiplying the values of two registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, computer-science, masm, irvine32

So let's say the registers ax = 50 and cx = 1000

after doing

```
mul cx
```

the hexadecimal product will be split in halves, in the form (dx ax)
How can I get the whole value of the product? (50,000 in this case)

Comment: It is `DX:AX` that the 32 bit result is in DX is the upper 16-bits and AX the lower 16-bits. Since the result of 50,000 can fit in just a 16-bit register, DX will be zero and AX will have 50,000.

Comment: Is that 1000 and 50 hex or decimal? My comment above assumed decimal. So is it 0x1000*0x50 or 1000*50

Comment: you're right, it's a decimal

Comment: but what if the product was more than the limit for 16 bits? what if the product was 100,000? how would I be able to obtain the product in that case? thanks a lot for the help btw

Comment: If the result was let us say 100,000 decimal.Convert the result to hex which would be 0x186A0. The lower 4 digits will go into AX and the upper 4 digits into DX. 0x186A0 is the same as 0x000186A0 (I added extra 0s to make it 8 digits for clarity). DX=0x0001 and AX=0x86A0

Comment: if I wanted to do some operation with 100,000, how can I "combine" DX and AX to get a whole value of 100,000?

Comment: That is a trickier question depending on the operation. How big a number do you intend to support? I now see this says irvine32. If you are doing 32-bit code then you can mul EAX and ECX (32-bit registers that combine to support a 64-bit result in EDX:EAX)

Comment: I think that'll work, thank you so much!

Comment: or you can just use `imul eax, ecx` and get the 32-bit result without the high bits (which will be faster)

Comment: The product isn't hex, it's binary integers.  Hexadecimal is a human-readable text serialization format for binary numbers, not used internally.

Comment: the `dx:ax` pair contains whole value. What do you mean exactly by "how can I get whole value"? If it is 100k, it can't fit into 16 bit, so you can't fit it into `ax`, so that dx=1, ax=34464 is already "whole value" when you treat "dx:ax" as 32 bit integer. (if you are programming for CPUs 8086..80286 without 32b registers, it will take some more work to operate with such value further, you will have to write code which does the 32 bit math with 16b registers.. on 80386+ CPUs you can use 32b instructions instead from start, like that `imul eax,ecx` example.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using <kbd>irvine32</kbd>, you are capable of writing 32 bit code.
It really makes no sense to program 16-bit in 2018 anymore. 32-bit code was introduced in 1985, you should move on now.

That being said.

```
mov ax,[a]       //part a
mov cx,[b]       //part b
mul cx         //ax:dx = a * b
cmp dx,0       //if dx=0 then ax contains the whole result
jne overflow   //handle overflow
//process ax
```

If you join the world of sane people, you can just do

```
movzx eax, word ptr [a]
movzx ecx, word ptr [b]
imul eax,ecx              //eax=eax*ecx
//test to see if it fits into a word
cmp eax,0xFFFF
ja,overflow               //result does not fit into a word.
//or, test to see if it fits into a (signed) int
js,overflow
```

If you're going to store the result in an `unsigned int`, then you don't need to test it.

Because your inputs are positive 16-bits, the output can never overflow a 32-bit unsigned destination. Another benefit of `imul` is that **if** you use the two-operand version, it does not clobber the `edx` register.

See: [IMUL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html)

**'How can I get the whole value [...]? (50,000 [...]'**
`ax` is a 16 bit register, **if** you use it as an unsigned word, then it can hold values from 0 to 65535. Because the destination of the calculation is `dx:ax` the sign bits go into `dx`.
BUT, `mul` is an unsigned multiply, so you **should not** feed it negative values.
If you want signed multiply, use `imul`.
You can also use `imul` for unsigned multiply, as long as you can ensure that the most significant bits of your two inputs are zero. (this is what `movzx` does).

Comment: If you don't change the size of `a` and `b`, you can't just `mov eax, a` if it's still a `word`.  You might want `movzx eax, word ptr [a]` / `movzx eax, word ptr [b]` / `imul eax, ecx`.  If you're not going to use the high half, it makes no sense to use legacy one-operand `mul` either; it's slower and clobbers EDX.